# remove session id from url

Tags: php, url-parsing

I want to develope simple web crawler, to grabb pages from several web sites and maintain them in actual condition. Some of this sites has session ids on each link, they doesn't store sesion ids in cookies at all. So, if i will parse site several times - my parsing table will containts dublicate pages with difference only in session id.

So my question is: how can I remove session id from all links, is there some intelligent idea? I'm developing on **php**, but all other platforms solutions will be useful, even just alhoritm on words.

Comment: For actual suggestions you should specify what language/platform you are working on

Comment: please read my last sentence more carefully

Comment: @hippout: If you put such information in tags, people don't have to ask, and might actually read the question.

Comment: my question doesn't about php implementation of this problem, i'm need just idea or algorithm of solution

Comment: You cannot be sure what part of the URL is actually the session ID. If in the URL query, some languages/frameworks have default names (*PHPSESSID*, *JSESSIONID*, etc.) or use a custome name (*SESSID*, *sid*, etc.). But other languages/frameworks incorporate the session ID into the URL path like `/<session-id>/foo/bar`.

Comment: @Gumbo I believe a latter one will never go public (and be subject of parsing). Otherwise it's going to be awful idea. Good link will never have permanent value in a query string and never have a temporary value in the path.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: APS.NET does that: [Understand How the ASP.NET Cookieless Feature Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As an Example, if you wanna use an RegEx this would remove all Sessions from your url (as long as they have 32 chars, which is the usual I guess):

`$url = preg_replace('#([\w\d]+=[\w\d]{32})#',null,$url);`

Comment: it is as usual as the variable name. usual, but not always. see session.hash_bits_per_character. thought +1 for regexp

Comment: Apart from [session.hash_bits_per_character](http://php.net/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character) see also [session.hash_function](http://php.net/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function). And this only covers standard PHP session IDs.

Comment: yepp, i think as someone really customizes them its nearly impossible to fetch them

Comment: This answer is "wrong", because example.com/?session=xxx becomes example.com/? leaving the question mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a regular expression for matching session keys, they're typical most of the time (PHPSESSID). Anyways, if you're crawling something and would like to accept and work with cookies, you should use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (see [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) COOKIE, COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR).

Comment: i seen several unique session keys, of course i can log this keys and use this info in next crawlings, but it isn't universal solution

Comment: maybe you can read it from the cookie HTTP headers, anyways @Hannes seems to have a better solution, since 32-char sessions string are more difficult to change than the session key name, yet it's still not 100%

Comment: a combination of hannes and kovshenin is the best. accept cookies to avoid getting session ids in url and remove it from the url on the second request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parse_str() and http_build_query() to extract, clear and rebuild the URL parameters. You can use regular expressions, but I think it would just be easier to get an array of the URL params to work with.

```
parse_str('session=123445&data=example&action=demo', $url_params);
// $url_params is now an associative array of the url params
unset($url_params['session'], $url_params['action']);
$new_url_param_string = http_build_query($url_params);
```

Comment: This works with any url formatted string, it doesn't matter what the key-name pairs are, it creates an associative array of what is there. You can then check for sid, SID, session, etc.